# Odd storage.googleapis.com link in spam email

Tags: email, google, spam

I have accidentally clicked on a link in a spam mail (sent to my gmail, wasn't sent to junk folder) and it opened the link in a new firefox tab. `hxxps://hm_vqh3bo6.storage.googleapis.com/24476060.html` which brought me to the google search home page.

What do I need to do now? Do I need to change my password immediately?

Is this a harmless link?

Comment: It's a redirect to a redirect to... an empty page, for me.  No way to tell what it was serving when you visited it.  But it's clearly malicious based on the pattern of redirects.

Comment: @gowenfawr, sent to my Gmail and I'm using a browser.

Comment: That duplicate answer seems to jump straight to a worst-case scenario. As long as your browser is updated, it is unlikely the computer is infected.